# ember computed not being updated

Tags: javascript, ember.js, javascript-objects, ember-components, ember-controllers

i have a computed property in ember

```
  isCurrentUserLikeIt: Ember.computed('likestatuses.@each.user_id', function () {
    const userId = parseInt(this.commonService.getId());
    const likestatuses = this.get('likestatuses');

    return likestatuses.filterBy('user_id', userId).get('length') !== 0;
  })
```

the computed property must be updated when user invoke an action.

```
this.doSave("likestatus", likestatus).then(function (result) {
        if (result.userlike) {
          const likestatuses = context.get('likestatuses');
          likestatuses.push(likestatusItem);
          context.set('likestatuses', likestatuses);
        } else {
          const likestatuses = context.get('likestatuses').filter(function (item) {
            return item.user_id !== userId
          });
          context.set('likestatuses', likestatuses);
        }

        context.debug(context.get('likestatuses'));
      });
```

the `isCurrentUserLikeIt` property is updated when the statement in `this.doSave`, is in else. but when the statement is in `if (result.userlike)` the `isCurrentUserLikeIt` property did not change :(

can anyone solve this

Answer (score 1):

In `if` check, you need to use [`pushObject`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy/methods/pushObject?anchor=pushObject) instead of `push`, this is the one will trigger computed property to recalculate and observer to trigger and template to update it to new value.

```
likestatuses.pushObject(likestatusItem);
```